# Norms of Wigner matrices under power law decay

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, statistical-physics

Suppose $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag}(h)$ where $h=(1^{-p},2^{-p},3^{-p},\ldots,d^{-p})$ and $p> 1$

$X$ is a matrix with $b$ rows sampled independently from $\operatorname{Normal}(0,\Sigma)$

Suppose $d$ is large. How does $\left\|\frac{1}{b}XX^T\right\|_{\operatorname{op}}$ depend on $b$?

For $p=1,d=30$, the formula below gives a nice fit to the average value observed in simulation, can it be improved/generalized?

$$\left\|\frac{1}{b}XX^T\right\|_{\operatorname{op}}\approx\frac{1}{b}\left(\|h\|_1+(1+b)\|h\|_\infty\right)$$

[image]
[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/stats.SE-wishart-spectral-norm.nb)

The formula [comes from analogy](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436131/7655) with Frobenius norm where Wick's theorem can be applied.

Comment: What is the norm considered? Frobenius norm? Operator norm associated to canonical Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^b$? It should be precised.

Comment: Operator norm, edited question to clarify